# Get HTML page source using SOCKETS VB.NET

Tags: html, vb.net, parsing

I am developing a program that gets the html source code of a certain webpages in a website.

I already developed one program that does so here's the code

```
     Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest =     System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(TextBox2.Text)
     Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()

     Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New      System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())

     Dim sourcecode As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
     TextBox1.Text = sourcecode
```

Recently, I found out that I could do the same using Sockets. This time I want to parse HTML of those web pages SIMULTANEOUSLY. I tried parsing simultaneously on my previous program using multithreading but my bandwidth keeps decreasing as threads increase so, to make my questions short,

- **How can I parse many web pages' source SIMULTANEOUSLY without decreasing my Bandwidth?**
- **Does using Sockets in multi threading decrease Bandwidth? (If anyone tried)**

***If my question wasn't clear, please feel free to correct me and I'd gladly accept any advice you can give.***

Answer (score 0):

If you are using multiple simultaneous network connections then perhaps it isn't so strange that you use up more bandwidth than if you stay with just one connection?

Each socket is basically a connection, so by creating more of them and transferring data over the connections, you thus increase the bandwidth your application is trying to use.

Comment: Thanks but is there a possible way that I could do to make something like a virtual socket or something that may bypass the limit

Comment: @BasilioBautistaAlucilja, think of your internet connection like a big pipe. It can only pass so much at any one time. No matter how few or many connections you have open the size of the pipe remains the same. With many connections, you may see bandwidth per connection drop as the pipe reaches its capacity. Ideally, you would want to create enough connections at one time that would cause your connection to slow slightly, as this means that you are fully utilizing all your available bandwidth.

Comment: Seems I get the feeling that It is not possible to bypass the limit for connection... Any Ideas or logic to get faster results when getting page source of a web page?